# Is there a way to fetch indices of original row after filtering in multiple columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Columns: `id, message, date, time`

There're multiple rows of same id and same message but different date & time. I tried

`df.groupby('id')[['date', 'time']].max()`

but this would give me id with latest date & time. But I need the entire columns. Is there a way to retain original indices after filtering using `groupby` or other ways to do this ?

##### What my data looks like:

| id | message | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 2021-01-02 | 01:34:23 |
| 1 | hi | 2021-01-01 | 12:01:11 |
| 2 | hello | 2021-03-02 | 11:11:12 |
| 2 | hello | 2021-02-11 | 05:10:12 |

##### Output should be

| id | message | date | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hi | 2021-01-02 | 01:34:23 |
| 2 | hello | 2021-03-02 | 11:11:12 |

Comment: could you give an example input and a desirable output?

Comment: I hope my solution working well for you, added one alternative to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices for datetimes by joined both columns for maximal values per groups and select rows by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
df1 = df.loc[s.groupby(df['id']).idxmax()]

print (df1)
   id message        date      time
0   1      hi  2021-01-02  01:34:23
2   2   hello  2021-03-02  11:11:12
```

**Details**:

```
print (s.groupby(df['id']).idxmax())
id
1    0
2    2
dtype: int64
```

EDIT:

If date column has not string but `date`s there is error:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'] + ' ' + df['time'])
```

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.date' and 'str'

Possible solution:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['time'].astype(str))
```

EDIT:

If need sorting by both columns and then remove duplicates:

```
df = df.sort_values(['date','time']).drop_duplicates('id', keep='last')
print (df)
   id message        date      time
0   1      hi  2021-01-02  01:34:23
2   2   hello  2021-03-02  11:11:12
```

Comment: This doesn't exactly solves the problem as date doesn't have to be in order. But sorting based on date & time will do. I sorted them on date -time and removed all the duplicates(based on id). Thanks.

Comment: @noitanec - Do yopu think solution from `EDIT` ?